# argparse on demand imports for types, choices etc

Tags: python, argparse

I have quite a big program which has a CLI interaction based on `argparse`, with several sub parsers. The list of supported choices for the subparsers arguments are determined based on DB queries, parsing different xml files, making different calculations etc, so it is quite IO intensive and time consuming.

The problem is that argparse seems to fetch `choices` for all sub parser when I run the script, which adds a considerable and annoying startup delay.

Is there a way to make `argparse` only fetch and validate `choices` for the currently used sub parser?

One solution could be to move all the validation logic deeper inside the code but that would mean quite a lot of work which I would like to avoid, if possible.

Thank you

Comment: If the choices are dynamic (the result of calculations), how does the user know what the choices are? Does the user have to run the program twice -- once to see the help message, and then a second time to actually run the program? That would be bad, since it would require the generation of choices to occur twice.

Comment: If you set up the `choices` as a DB table, you might be able add [DB triggers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger) so that as other DB tables change, the appropriate commands can be run to update the table of `choices`. To handle the changing XML files, you could use [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) to update the `choices` DB table when the XML files change... If you do it this way, then your program can simply read the `choices` DB table to prepare `argparse`.

Comment: The `choices` are used as validation only as the amount of available options is big and the help text becomes unreadable. I am using `metavar` attribute to format the help text. This is ok because, normally, the users know/guess the available options but they might do typing mistakes or similar. Regarding, db triggers and watchdog, it sounds like an interesting option. I will look into it. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: If you don't need the choices for help display, it might be simpler to do your own validation after `parse_args`.  You can still use parser's error mechanism (though with subparsers that might be more difficult).

Comment: It might be possible to write a lazy choices.  The choices object needs a `__contains__` (to respond to `in`) for testing.  It also needs to be iterable (to generate the error messsage).  `list`, `set`,`dict` are the usual objects, but you could write your own class that gives the same sort of functionality - but only on-demand.

Comment: `Ipython` makes extensive use of `argparse`.  Many of argument definitions come from config files.  So the values can be set in the default config files, your custom profile file, or the command line.  It generates its own help (capturing `-h` before calling `parse_args`). The magic commands also parse their arguments with argparse. `plac` is another example of generating a parser programmatically - based on function arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delay the fetching of choices, you could parse the command-line in two stages: In the first stage, you find only the subparser, and in the second stage, the subparser is used to parse the rest of the arguments:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('subparser', choices=['foo','bar'])

def foo_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('fooval', choices='123')
    return parser

def bar_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('barval', choices='ABC')
    return parser

dispatch = {'foo':foo_parser, 'bar':bar_parser}
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
args = dispatch[args.subparser]().parse_args(unknown)
print(args)
```

It could be used like this:

```
% script.py foo 2
Namespace(fooval='2')

% script.py bar A
Namespace(barval='A')
```

Note that the top-level help message will be less friendly, since it can only tell you about the subparser choices:

```
% script.py -h
usage: script.py [-h] {foo,bar}
...
```

To find information about the choices in each subparser, the user would have to select the subparser and pass the `-h` to it:

```
% script.py bar -- -h
usage: script.py [-h] {A,B,C}
```

All arguments after the `--` are considered non-options (to `script.py`) and are thus parsed by the `bar_parser`.

Comment: I've tried this out and it works fine. One drawback is that it basically creates a custom way to handle sub parsers instead of using `argparse` built in sub parsers, but this is working ok for my project.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty example of a 'lazy' choices.  In this case choices are a range of integers.  I think a case that requires expensive DB lookups could implemented in a similar fashion.

```
# argparse with lazy choices

class LazyChoice(object):
    # large range
    def __init__(self, argmax):
        self.argmax=argmax
    def __contains__(self, item):
        # a 'lazy' test that does not enumerate all choices
        return item<=self.argmax
    def __iter__(self):
        # iterable for display in error message
        # use is in:
        # tup = value, ', '.join(map(repr, action.choices))
        # metavar bypasses this when formatting help/usage
        return iter(['integers less than %s'%self.argmax])

import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--regular','-r',choices=['one','two'])
larg = parser.add_argument('--lazy','-l', choices=LazyChoice(10))
larg.type = int
print parser.parse_args()
```

Implementing the testing part (`__contains__`) is easy.  The help/usage can be customized with `help` and `metavar` attributes.  Customizing the error message is harder.  http://bugs.python.org/issue16468 discusses alternatives when `choices` are not iterable.  (also on long list choices: http://bugs.python.org/issue16418)

I've also shown how the `type` can be changed after the initial setup.  That doesn't solve the problem of setting type based on subparser choice.  But it isn't hard to write a custom `type`, one that does some sort of Db lookup.  All a `type` function needs to do is take a string, return the correct converted value, and raise `ValueError` if there's a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue by creating a simple `ArgumentParser` subclass:

```
import argparse

class ArgumentParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.lazy_init = None

    def parse_known_args(self, args=None, namespace=None):
        if self.lazy_init is not None:
            self.lazy_init()
            self.lazy_init = None

        return super().parse_known_args(args, namespace)
```

Then I can use it as following:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command', title='commands', parser_class=ArgumentParser)
subparsers.required = True

subparser = subparsers.add_parser(
    'do-something', help="do something",
    description="Do something great.",
)

def lazy_init():
    from my_database import data

    subparser.add_argument(
        '-o', '--option', choices=data.expensive_fetch(), action='save',
    )

subparser.lazy_init = lazy_init
```

This will really initialize a sub-parser only when parent parser tries to parse arguments for the sub-parser. So if you do `program -h` it will not initialize the sub-parser, but if you do `program do-something -h` it will.

Answer (score 0):

This is a script that tests the idea of delaying the creation of a subparser until it is actually needed.  In theory it might save start up time, by only creating the subparser that's actually needed.

I use the `nargs=argparse.PARSER` to replicate the subparser behavior in the main parser.  `help` behavior is similar.

```
# lazy subparsers test
# lazy behaves much like a regular subparser case, but only creates one subparser
# for N=5 time differences do not rise above the noise

import argparse

def regular(N):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    sp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')
    for i in range(N):
        spp = sp.add_parser('cmd%s'%i)
        spp.set_defaults(func='cmd%s'%(10*i))
        spp.add_argument('-f','--foo')
        spp.add_argument('pos', nargs='*')
    return parser

def lazy(N):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    sp = parser.add_argument('cmd', nargs=argparse.PARSER, choices=[])
    for i in range(N):
        sp.choices.append('cmd%s'%i)
    return parser

def subpar(cmd):
    cmd, argv = cmd[0], cmd[1:]
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog=cmd)
    parser.add_argument('-f','--foo')
    parser.add_argument('pos', nargs='*')
    parser.set_defaults(func=cmd)
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    return args

N = 5
mode = True #False
argv = 'cmd1 -f1 a b c'.split()
if mode:
    args = regular(N).parse_args(argv)
    print(args)
else:
    args = lazy(N).parse_args(argv)
    print(args)
    if isinstance(args.cmd, list):
        sargs = subpar(args.cmd)
        print(sargs)
```

test runs with different values of `mode` (and N=5)

```
1004:~/mypy$ time python3 stack44315696.py 
Namespace(cmd='cmd1', foo='1', func='cmd10', pos=['a', 'b', 'c'])

real    0m0.052s
user    0m0.044s
sys 0m0.008s
1011:~/mypy$ time python3 stack44315696.py 
Namespace(cmd=['cmd1', '-f1', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
Namespace(foo='1', func='cmd1', pos=['a', 'b', 'c'])

real    0m0.051s
user    0m0.048s
sys 0m0.000s
```

`N` has to be much larger to start seeing a effect.